# Where is the mistake on creation the component in Angular 2.2?

Tags: angular

I want to create the component in Angular 2.2, but i get this mistake:

> 'app-spinner' is not a known element:
>   1. If 'app-spinner' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'app-spinner' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component

**This my code:**

**spinner.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [SpinnerComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule],
  providers: [],
})
export class SpinnerModule {}
```

**index.ts**

```
@Component({
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  selector: 'app-spinner',
  template: require('./spinner.html'),
})
export class SpinnerComponent {}
```

Comment: Are you importing `SpinnerModule` into the module where you are using the `SpinnerComponent`? Note that you have to export the component as well.

Comment: add this in exports also.

Comment: @dcg, I don't know where to import it. Can you show an example?

Comment: How did you create the spinner component. Using angular cli or manually?

Answer (score 1):

You can import the spinner module into another module like this:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [SpinnerModule],
  declarations: [
    // Current module's components here
  ]
})
export class UseSpinnerModule {}
```

In your `SpinnerModule` declaration  you have to export the component like:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // ...
  ],
  declarations: [SpinnerComponent],
  exports: [SpinnerComponent],
})
export class SpinnerModule {}
```

Hope it helps!

**EDIT**: After that you can use the spinner component wherever you want in your `UseSpinnerModule`'s components (`<app-spinner></app-spinner>`).